# Matrix inequalities and matrices

Tags: matrices

I try to understand matrix inequalities. What does A > B mean? The same is valid for A < B. We know that A = B is easy to comprehend, but the formers are confusing.

Best regards

-- post-edited

Consider a mass matrix $M$ with bounded terms dependent on x and p. The parameter p belongs to a partition with lower and upper value, such that M is not singular within it.

The remark above considers, if true, $M_{-} \leq M \leq M_{+}$, with subscripts - and + the evaluations on lower and upper values respectively.

An example: the simplest mass matrix I can imagine is the scalar m. If it belongs to $m_0 < m < m_1$, than the statement is true. A more cumbersome case is where my doubt lays.

Comment: It depends on the context.  Sometimes $A>B$ means that $A_{ij} > B_{ij}$ for all $i,j$.  Sometimes it means that $A - B$ is positive definite.

Comment: Are the forms equivalent or share some relation with the norm of both matrices somehow?

Comment: No, these notions of inequality are not equivalent.  I don't know what you mean by " share some relation with the norm of both matrices somehow".

Comment: A conjecuturate that if norm(A) > norm(B), than A > B.

Comment: No that statement does not hold for either norm.  It doesn't even hold for numbers: if $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, $|a|>|b|$ does not imply that $a>b$.

Comment: Bruno, where have you seen $A>B$ written?

Comment: I didn't see it anywhere. I just wondered and came here to see if it makes sense,

Comment: I thought it would be one of that naive question with relevant implications.

Comment: I added the actual state below the original post.